# Not able to import shapely.geometry

Tags: python, shapely

I am trying to import shapely but getting error.

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------- OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-9-62e74f53568a> in <module>
----> 1 import shapely.geometry

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/__init__.py in <module>
      2 """
      3 
----> 4 from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE
      5 from .geo import box, shape, asShape, mapping
      6 from .point import Point, asPoint

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py in <module>
     16 
     17 from shapely.affinity import affine_transform
---> 18 from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence
     19 from shapely.errors import WKBReadingError, WKTReadingError
     20 from shapely.geos import WKBWriter, WKTWriter

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/coords.py in <module>
      6 from ctypes import byref, c_double, c_uint
      7 
----> 8 from shapely.geos import lgeos
      9 from shapely.topology import Validating
     10 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py in <module>
    136         _lgeos = load_dll('geos_c', fallbacks=alt_paths)
    137 
--> 138     free = load_dll('c').free
    139     free.argtypes = [c_void_p]
    140     free.restype = None

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py in load_dll(libname, fallbacks, mode)
     60         raise OSError(
     61             "Could not find lib {} or load any of its variants {}.".format(
---> 62                 libname, fallbacks or []))
     63 
     64 _lgeos = None

OSError: Could not find lib c or load any of its variants [].
```

I tried `conda install -c conda-forge geos=3.7.1` but its not helping.

Can someone please help how can i repair Shapely. Shapely version I m using is 1.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried `conda install -c conda-forge geos=3.7.1` but it did not work.

---

I guess you are using an anaconda environment. So after you activate your environment in terminal;

```
conda activate <your_environment_name>
```

Using

```
pip install Shapely
```

in terminal, while my environment is active, I was able to use the package. Version is the 1.8.2, just like you wanted it.

---

For the possibility that you'd like to have a reminder on conda environments, [here is a wonderful link.](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)